# How do I configure spring security OAuth 2 password grant to display a custom login form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-rest

I have a Spring boot project that uses spring security OAuth 2, the project uses OAuth 2 password grant for authorization. Since this grant type requires that the user provide his credentials(username and password), then it also makes sense that the user should be provided with an interface to do so. The problem is that i can't find a good tutorial to use, all the tutorials i have seen rather use CURL but i want a form.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/WEBSHIVOM/OauthSpringBoot checkout this example

Comment: Thank you @this_is_om_vm ,But i'm looking for password grant not authorization code grant. I want users to be able to provide the username and password for each login.